# Hide or Change specific banner for signed in users

Tags: magento2, hide

We have a banner on our homepage that is saying "BECOME A MEMBER TODAY". We want to hide this banner or have it changed to a different banner when customers are signed in. We are using magento 2 with porto theme. Any good suggestions?

Comment: Please add code how that banner is added in you home via CMS or a widget ? There can be multiple ways depending on how it is added

Comment: below is the code inserted in our homepage slider banner:

Comment: --></style>
<div class="banner-wrap"><img class="banner-image" style="display: block; width: 100vw;" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/Warehouse.jpg"}}" alt="ifive warehouse" />
<div class="banner-content">
<h1 class="banner-title" style="text-align: center;"><strong>BECOME A MEMBER TODAY</strong></h1>
<h4 class="banner-desc" style="text-align: center;">LARGE SELECTION OF NEW, REFURBISHED &amp; GRADED DEVICES IN STOCK</h4>
<button class="button button-action"> <a style="color: #fff !important;" href="https://ifivewireless.com/customer/account/create/"> CREATE AN ACCOUNT</a></button></div>
</div>

Comment: <style xml="space"><!--
.banner-wrap {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
height: 278px ;
}

.banner-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.banner-title{
 font-size: 3rem;
font-weight : 500;
}

.banner-desc{
color : #fff;
line-height: 1.6;
font-size : 1.3rem;
margin-top : 1rem;
}

Comment: .banner-image{
width: width: 100vw;
height: 278px ;

}



.button-action {
    color: #fff !important;
    background: #0196F2 !important;
   
    text-align: center;

    padding: 0px 20px !important;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 0px !important;
    outline: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
transition: all 1s ease;
font-weight: 700 !important;
font-size: 12px !important;
}

.button-action:hover{
background: rgba(27, 36, 212) !important;
}

Comment: You can edit question and add it there

Comment: the question is how can we hide the banner's text and "create an account" button after customer actually signed in to their account. Currently all signed user when they view the home page they still see this banner with the following text: "BECOME A MEMBER TODAY" and the "create an account" button below it. We just want to hide it or just edit the text and button after the customers are logged in.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello Ran,**

You can use a cookie, with no expiry date. This cookie usually gets removed when browser is closed.

This should work:

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function(e){
if(docuement.cookie.indexOf('banner_removed=1') !== -1)
    document.getElementById('closeButton').parentNode.style.display = 'none';
});
document.getElementById('closeButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
document.cookie = "banner_removed=1";
}, false);
</script>
```

**Thanks**

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However this doesn't seems to solve our issue. The issue is when our customers login to their account they are still seeing our frontend homepage banner which we want only the unregistered users to see. That banner is basically saying " Become a member today" and has a "create an account" button. I would like to have that text on the banner removed or edit the text when an actual registered customer signed in. Signed in customer have no reason to see "BECOME A MEMBER TODAY" or "CREATE AN ACCOUNT" button since they are already registered.

Comment: Please add session for customer, that you want, your issue will solved, that i cant add that session in my code, you have to add this as per your requirements, Thanks please accept the answer, AS it do fulfill your Requirements, how much i can!

Comment: Which code should we insert and where to insert?

Comment: @Ran You have to create the controller for customer session. so you can hide the banner with different group that you want, as there is different group of customer, like signed in , general or guest! Please do accept this solution as this can helps others also, Thanks